# React Bootstrap is not rendering two columns in one row

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have installed these packages:

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap@5.1.3
```

Then I created a new project using `create-react-app`

Then in `index.html` (which is inside the public folder), I added:

```
<head>
...
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>

    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>

    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
...
</head>
```

After that, I created a `Home.js` file in `src` folder and added this code to it:

```
        <Container fluid>
            <Row>
                <Col>1 of 2</Col>
                <Col>2 of 2</Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
```

When I do `npm start` it takes some time to load (assuming it's linking the files) and after that, it shows both the columns in a stack as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the imports, make sure `bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css` is imported.

```
import {Container,Row,Col} from "react-bootstrap"
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```